# 3 column css template, bad position for right column

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

i'm trying to do a simple 3-columns template

This is my CSS code:

```
#page {
   padding: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 900px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   float: none;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#header {
   height: 250px;
   width: 900px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
#right-column {
   float: right;
   width: 200px;
}
#left-column {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
}
#center-column {
   width: 490px;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

And then my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title></head>

   <body>
      <div id="page">
         <div id="header">
            <img src="header.png" width="900" height="250" />
         </div>
         <div id="page-content">
            <div id="left-column">Content for  id "left-column" Goes Here</div>
            <div id="center-column">Content for  id "center-column" Goes Here</div>
            <div id="right-column">Content for  id "right-column" Goes Here</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

What i get is this:

[image: Output]

The question is: Why does my right column have this "margin" at the top? Left-column and Center-column are made the same way as center-right columns, but right column has this "margin", how do i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the columns should be floating left like so :

```
#right-column {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
}
#left-column {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;

}
#center-column {
   width: 490px;
   float:left;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/dCEhV/).

If you wanted that the page-content height fits the size of the floating content, you should use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/dCEhV/1/) for another example.

Comment: Worked, but i'll keep the right column floated to right, because i want it to be right-aligned with header, thanks a lot!!

Comment: To have a nice alignement, you need to have the widths sum to be the same that your container width, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/dCEhV/2/).

Comment: I know... Can you explain me why is it bad to `float:right` the right column?

Comment: It is not in your case, both ways are working for the right column.

Comment: Ok, but in general, why is it bad?

Comment: It is not, it depends on how you do things, see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/dCEhV/3/) `float:right` works, but `float:left` won't because of the html structure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual margin space on your right column.  It is floating right but the margin space on center column is making it so your total width of columns is greater than 100%.

A simple solution is to float everything left.  Be sure that your container is wide enough to fit 890px wide.

Try this...

```
#right-column {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
}
#left-column {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
}
#center-column {
   float: left;
   width: 490px;
}
```

Once you have this working, your next step is to start playing with % widths and % margins to make your templates responsive.  This allows your site to scale depending on width of the device viewing it.

Just be sure your total widths never exceed 100%, or your columns will not nest into their proper places.

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left` to the middle column.

```
#center-column {
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 490px;
}
```

Really you should `float:left;` all the columns, then `clear:both` after